# Thymeleaf th:each attribute failed on form element

Tags: thymeleaf

I find Thymeleaf `th:each` is not working properly on `<form>` element when `${items}` is empty.

```
<form th:each="item,iterStat : ${items}" >
    <span th:text="${iterStat.size}"> Hello </span>
</form>

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'size' cannot be found on null
```

But, it is ok on `<div>` element

```
<div th:each="item,iterStat : ${items}" >
    <span th:text="${iterStat.size}"> Hello </span>
</div>
```

The Thymeleaf is included in Spring Boot v1.5.4.RELEASE

Why?